# Simple ieteration/append loop not returning correct array:

Tags: python, arrays, loops, set, range

I have a six-line section of code:

```
setA = 101

for i in range(101):
    l = [0]
    q = i * 3
    f = str(q)
    print f
```

That prints the numbers upwards:

```
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
33
```

But I want them in an array, and so I changed it:

```
setA = 101

for i in range(101):
    l = [0]
    q = i * 3
    f = str(q)
    l.append(f)

print str(l)
```

But now, it only gives me a two-value array `[0, '300']`, and that's it. I have a feeling that I'm missing something really, really basic. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting your array with each iteration:

```
for i in range(101):
    l = [0]
```

Move that out of your loop and it'll work:

```
l = []
for i in range(101):
    q = i * 3
    f = str(q)
    l.append(f)

print str(l)
```

Comment: Doesn't it contain two instances of `0` at the beginning of the list?

Answer (score -1):

You could use python's list comprehension:

```
l = [i*3 for i in range(101)]
# Variable l now contains a list of integers

l_str = [str(i) for i in range(101)]
# l_str is a list of strings (if you need string or going to print them)

# if you need to print it out you can use this construction
print('\n'.join(l_str))
```

Comment: Don't use `_` as a variable name unless you intend for it to be ignored. Since you are actually using the value give it a name. You're also needlessly making a O(2n) operation. You pass the calculation directly to `str()`

Comment: @IanAuld to your second part of comment, I don't know what is the type of variables he wants. He's need an list of integers or strings? As he mentioned he doesn't want to print them out. So does it should be a list of strings? For me it's better to use list of integers. I just give some options.

Comment: It's perfectly clear that he casts them as strings and then adds them to the list. If you're not clear on something ask a question in a comment don't just guess.